# asp.net mvc. Sending data through Get (form) and returning success in a label?(how to send and return data to the same view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm struggling to learn how .net mvc works. I've been trying to make sort of a anagram checker, but before that i'm making an input and send through GET (form) to the controller, and want to check for a word if it's equal with another( ex word1 == word1). and if that's true i want to send back to the view 'success' as a string to be written in a label. 
So i have a question. First i know how to send data through get and so far i checked if a word is equal with something and if that's true then i redirected to index.
What i don't know if how can i send that 'success' back to the same view (without ajax if possible) and to write it in a label so i input a text and if that's equal with mine then it will say success under 
The controller:

```
       {
           if ( word == "word1")
           {
               //return HttpNotFound();
               return RedirectToAction("Index");

           }
           return View();
       }
```

the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CheckAnagram";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CheckAnagram</h2>




@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckAnagram", "Anagrams", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBox("word", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Check for anagrams" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```

i know i can send a model to view but then when i reload the page it will send it again, so i can't understand how to make this work properly, what is the normal way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TempData` to pass model data to a redirect request. You can pass simple types like string, int, Guid etc. If you want to pass a complex type object via TempData, you have can serialize your object to a string and pass that. In your scenario, you can do this:

```
{
 if ( word == "word1")
 { 
  TempData["myresult"] = "Word match";
  //return HttpNotFound();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
 return View();
}
```

And your `Index` method will look like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (TempData["myresult"] !=null)
    {
        var myresult= TempData["myresult"];
        ViewBag.myresult=myresult;
    }
    return View();
}
```

And in your `Index` view, you can simply retrieve the `ViewBag` value to be displayed.

Comment: thank you! But i'm wondering about viewbag because from what i learned is not the best way to use it, sending things through viewbag doesn't have intelisense and everyone seems to say it's not the best way of doing things. what do you think about this?

Comment: @sgcata Well, it totally depends on your requirement.  I prefer to use `ViewBag` for sending messages to the View but if I have to send actual concrete data to be used, then I prefer a model that is binded to my data.  You would have to look for `ViewModel` and how they are used in MVC. And you can also send `Model` data through a redirect using `TempData`